# OpenGL 2D Hex Board shaped like a Rhombus

Tags: c++, opengl, hex, 2d

So I am working on a GUI for a Hex Board game. Hex game has 121 Hex Shapes in an 11 by 11 Rhombus. I have drawn an 11 by 11 board that is shaped like a Quad or a square. How would I go about translating the coordinates to draw the Hex shapes like a rhombus? Here is the piece of my code that draws the board every frame.

```
    void draw_Board(HexBoard* h) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1.5f, 1.5f, 0.0f);
    for (auto iter = h->drawList.begin(); iter != h->drawList.end(); ++iter) {
        pointRef t = *iter;
        colorRef c;
        float scale_factor = h->get_scale_factor();
        if (t.player == 0) {
            c.red = 1;
            c.green = 1;
            c.blue = 1;
        }
        else if (t.player == 1) {
            c.red = 1;
            c.green = 0;
            c.blue = 0;
        }
        else if (t.player == 2) {
            c.red = 0;
            c.green = 0;
            c.blue = 1;
        }

        int x_increment = 2;
        int y_increment = 2;

        glPushMatrix();
        //cout << t.x_pos << " " << t.y_pos << endl;
        //cout << c.red << " " << c.green << " " << c.blue << endl;
        glTranslatef(t.x_pos * 2 , t.y_pos * 2, 0);
        draw_Hex(c, scale_factor);
        glPopMatrix();

    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Here is how my board looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRanK.jpg

Goal shape is this 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Hex-board-11x11-%282%29.jpg

Comment: I recommend http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/ as a definitive guide

Answer (score 2):

**You need to grasp the basic trigonometry behind hexagons**

[image: hexagon steps]

as you can see there are two valid angles `30` and `60` degrees. I assume you have no problem of obtaining the hexagon points itself so focus on the `i,j` step in the grid then:

- `i-step` is `2*dx` which is `2.0*r*cos(30deg)` in x-axis
- `j-step` changes booth x and y and it is
- `dx` in x-axis and `2.0*dx*sin(60deg)` in y-axis

now just create loop through your grid and compute each hexagon start point ...
This is the result for 10x10 grid:

[image: example]

**Here the source in C++:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <math.h>
const float hexagon_r=0.2;
const float hexagon_dx=hexagon_r*cos(30.0*M_PI/180.0);
const float hexagon_dy=hexagon_r*sin(30.0*M_PI/180.0);
const float hexagon_gx=2.0*hexagon_dx;
const float hexagon_gy=2.0*hexagon_dx*sin(60.0*M_PI/180.0);
void draw_hexagon(float x,float y,float z)
    {
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(x-hexagon_dx,y-hexagon_dy,z);
    glVertex3f(x-hexagon_dx,y+hexagon_dy,z);
    glVertex3f(x           ,y+hexagon_r ,z);
    glVertex3f(x+hexagon_dx,y+hexagon_dy,z);
    glVertex3f(x+hexagon_dx,y-hexagon_dy,z);
    glVertex3f(x           ,y-hexagon_r ,z);
    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw_hexagon_grid(float x,float y,float z,int ni,int nj)
    {
    int i,j; float x0;
    x-=float(ni-1)*hexagon_gx*0.5; // just shift x,y to start position (i=0,j=0)
    x-=float(nj-1)*hexagon_dx*0.5;
    y-=float(nj-1)*hexagon_gy*0.5;
    for (x0=x,j=0;j<nj;j++,x0+=hexagon_dx,x=x0,y+=hexagon_gy)
     for (i=0;i<ni;i++,x+=hexagon_gx)
      draw_hexagon(x,y,z);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Usage is simple: `draw_hexagon_grid(0.0,0.0,-7.0,10,10);`

- `x,y,z` is the center point of grid (I have **3D** view therefore I got `z=-7` just to get the grid before camera)
- `ni,nj` is the grid size in `x` and `y` axis

you can ignore the `z` axis ...